# Window.open not working, boolean is not a function

Tags: javascript, facebook, window

I know there is a lot of question about this but I check all of them, nothing with the same error (I might have missed one or two post)..

So, I get this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/) to know how to open a facebook share window inside the current window in order to have my own share button.

But this fiddle is not working on my local.
I didn't change the code first to test so it's not because I change something.

Chrome's console throw me this error pointed on the `window.open()`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function
```

What I missed ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, the problem don't come from there,

Did you overwrited the function "open" in your code? like a global variable that you have set as a boolean ?

just ctlr + F your scripts to find a "open" or "var open" ^^

Comment: Yes I did sorry, i didn't try with "var open" and I missed it. Damn.
Thank you !